# Is it polite to ask the company to mention the future raise -which we had discussed in interview -in their written offer?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, raise, california

I got an offer from a company who just verbally told me "we will give you this much and after 60 days if you were doing well, we will give you a raise for a higher rate ." which they specified.
So my question is; Is it polite to ask them to mention this in their written offer?

Answer (score 191):

If it isn't in writing, it doesn't exist.  If you don't see it in the written offer, by all means mention it.

It is not impolite, it is being diligent and making sure all the terms agreed upon are met.

Comment: The OP should have `if you were doing well` quantified or specified in detail. Even if included on a written offer, that's not language that would likely to be enforceable  without dispute.

Comment: @ExactaBox exactly.  If it is not defined, they can deny the raise for any reason.

Comment: Agreed, no reason for them not to put it in the contract, my new offer has something very similar

Answer (score 70):

Yes, absolutely.

If it's not in writing, you'll have a hard time making a case for it if they "go weird" on you.

A reputable company never has an issue with putting a promise in writing.  A company that has an issue with it is probably not one you want to work for, anyway.

Answer (score 36):

It would be very wise to put this in writing, however if this is tied to their subjective perceived opinion of you doing good, and not tied to any specific and hard metric easy to measure, the offer will not be worth the paper it is written on.

Actually HR tried to pull this one on me on a very well paid contract in the past, offering me less 20% than I was asking, and the rest be on condition on a *positive* evaluation 6 months in the future. Fortunately I had the presence of mind to tell them, either they gave me the full amount, or I would not be interested in the position.

Much later on, through the grapevine, I found out they did that stunt to all people working for that company, only as a strategy to get the salary down, and never followed up on their promise.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn’t matter if you have this in writing or not. The company is not going to give you the raise.

This company is so cheap they are suggesting they will pay you less for two months. They are either very tight cash flow or they enjoy playing mind control games with their employees.

There will be a reason in two months for not giving you the raise. You shouldn’t accept the offer unless you you get the salary you want from day 1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79932/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-mz-is-it-polite-to-ask-the-company-to-mention-the-fu).

Answer (score 6):

It is all about asking it politely.

- Do not sceptically ask to put that promise in wirting
- Better ask them for details on the promise (when it will happen and how it will be evaluated
- Or if you had enought details oraly: summarise them in writing and ask more details on what they consider to be a good performance.

Comment: I am always sceptic about such promises. I realize you are not suggesting to be dishonest, just to be polite. But it is a shame that being sceptic about a promise from a group of people I just recently came to know and with which I'm starting a working relationship is frowned upon. It should rather be considered normal and even expected behaviour in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 4):

First let me say I am all in favor of politeness, politeness is the grease that gets things done smoothly and efficiently.

But politeness is a method not a goal.  You want to do X politely, not be polite.

In your particular you seem to have three possibly conflicting goals, getting it in writing that you will get a raise shortly after being hired, getting a raise shortly after being hired, and of course getting hired. You want a method of asking for the first goal that minimally impacts the third goal, in order to enhance your chances of achieving the second goal.

Politeness is obviously your go to tool in this case. But you need to decide not whether it is polite to ask for it in writing, but whether asking will reduce your chances of achieving the other goals (and determine how that effects your desire to work there).

My advice would be to simply ask for it, something along the lines of "During our discussions X said that the starting salary would be reassessed after Y, could you please include that in the written offer? Thanks"